# Valuing the floating leg of a swap

Tags: fixed-income, swaps, interest-rate-swap

Let $P_{t}(\pi)$ be the price at time t of a zero coupon bond with time to maturity $\pi$. Furthermore, let $f_{t}(\pi_1, \pi_2)$ be the forward rate that is earned over the time period $[\pi_1, \pi_2]$. Suppose that we are now at time $t=0$ and want to value an interest rate swap over 5 periods with notional amount 1.  We should value both the fixed leg and the floating leg.

Clearly, for the fixed leg with swap rate 1% we have $$PV_{fixed}=0.01\sum_{\pi=1}P_{0}(\pi)$$

But I dont understand why we also have $$PV_{floating}=\sum_{\pi=1}^{5}f_0(\pi-1,\pi)P_{0}(\pi)$$

What do the forward rates have to do with the floating rates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward rates are the implied, no-arbitrage floating rate in the 'future'.  I use this term loosely here because nobody really pretends that these rates are actually realized in the future, but, mathematically, forward rates are implied fundamentally as:
The rate that would make you indifferent between locking in an interest rate from t0 to t1 and then rolling into another (pre-decided rate) between t1 and t2, or just one, "spot" rate from t0 to t2 outright.

Mathematically:
\begin{equation}
(1+f_{0,1})*(1+f_{1,2}) = (1+r_{0,2})
\end{equation}
(note that i ignored compounding and conventions to show the simple case, so this assumes each forward is only compounded for the single period and day-counts perfectly match)

where technically
\begin{equation}
f_{0,1}=FloatingRate_{0}
\end{equation}that is, the first forward rate is the first/current known floating rate.

The implied forwards of the current floating rate are used for pricing the legs of the swap to get 0 NPV (assuming vanilla swap). If you have a full forwards curve, or a full zero curve, then you can simply solve for the other (assuming the times align, if not you have to use what is called 'stub rates', but won't get into that).

When it comes to swap value, qualitatively the link between floating and forward rates are simply: if the floating rate does not follow the path of the initial implied forwards (at entry of the swap contract), then the value of the swap will change. At first this statement may seem strange, because often swaps are viewed as a bet on the fixed rate leg and that rate moving up and down. But think about how the swap is valued. In theoretical pricing we solve for the fixed leg (in practice you may find yourself solving for a spread to the float leg, but won't get into that here). So what actually causes the fixed leg to change? Well, if the zero curve moves (or par curve on which zero rates are implied) then now your implied forwards have changed! Obviously now your swap has changed in value from the 0NPV entry point (ok... it's possible things shift in ways that it stays near 0... but you get the point). So in reality it makes more sense to think about a swap as a bet on implied forward rates, but nobody really does because it is easier to measure in dollar value of basis point terms on the fixed leg.

If I understood your question this should help establish the relationship between floating and forward rates. I would point out that when I say "0NPV" it is not because the PV of each legs is zero, but rather the difference between the two is zero, so that in aggregate the two legs cancel out in PV upon entry.

---

Forwards and how they relate to discount factors (which are present values of zero coupon bonds. I admit some of your subscripts confuse me a bit just because I'm not used to seeing it that way, but it looks correct to me so hopefully you can relate the following back to your notation):

\begin{equation}
(1+f_{0,1})(1+f_{1,2})=(1+r_{0,2})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1/(1+f_{0,1})*1/(1+f_{1,2})=1/(1+r_{0,2})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
where: 1/(1+r)=DF
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
DF_{0,1}*1/(1+f_{1,2})=DF_{0,2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
DF_{0,1}/DF_{0,2}=(1+f_{1,2})
\end{equation}
I purposely left the forward rate because this is often how I've seen the relationship stated, however if we take 1/ both sides, it is equivalent to:
\begin{equation}
DF_{0,2}/DF_{0,1}=DF_{1,2}
\end{equation}
but \begin{equation} DF_{1,2}\end{equation} doesnt really have much economic intuition (it's a 'future present value' so to speak) in practice, so it is avoided, but we can still reconcile to your formula in the comments:
Firstly, lets get this out of the way:
\begin{equation}
DF_{0,t}=P_0(t)=1/(1+r_t)
\end{equation}
In the general case where we allow for different time periods we then have:
\begin{equation}
P_0(t)/P_0(t-1)=P_{t-1}(t)
\end{equation}
simple rearrange:
\begin{equation}
P_0(t)/P_{t-1}(t)=P_0(t-1)
\end{equation}
where i've used t instead of pi, which IMO is less confusing, and I think the formula you have in the comments erroneously uses both.

Comment: Your answer makes intuitively clear why floating and forward rates are related, I still do have a question about obtaining the present value of the floating leg mathematically which seems to be related to your first equation: Why does it hold that the present value of $\frac{1}{P_{t-1}(1)}$ at time t=0 is given by $P_{0}(\pi-1)$, which in equation form basically says that:

$$\frac{P_{0}(\pi)}{P_{t-1}(1)}=P_{0}(\pi-1)$$  I saw this argument being used in proving the present value formula of the floating leg.

Comment: @Joogs added a section in the answer that should help reconcile the use of discount factors (equivalent to zero coupon prices). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_rate has some useful info on these things as well, and can help show this relationship under different compounding frequencies as well.

Comment: Thank you for this, I understand all your steps but I cannot seem to connect the dots to how all of this leads to the expression in my comment above, which states that the present value of the gross return of a bond at time t-1 with time to maturity 1 is equal to the price of a bond now with time to maturity $t-1$.

Comment: Ok i figured out your issue. lets assume only 2 periods. t0=now and t2=maturity t1 in between. using price instead of DF from my answer:
\begin{equation}
P_0(t_2)/P_0(t_1)=P_1(t_2)
\end{equation}
Since in your initial question you are talking about 5 periods, if we make time dynamic, where time reference = pi changes then we get your last formula:
\begin{equation}
P_0(\pi)/P_0(\pi-1)=P_{pi-1}(\pi)
\end{equation}
And voila! (fwiw I would avoid using pi for time... and in your last you have t and pi as relative time... which doesn't make sense to me. I think that is an error).

Comment: I realise there is actually something in your answer that I dont understand: if I correctly interpret your answer then you are basically saying that $$(1+f_{1,2})^{-1}=DF_{1,2}=(1+r_{1,2})^{-1}$$, why does that hold?

Comment: i initially used r as reference to a 'spot rate' (r in rate), and f to denote a forward rate, but i can see how that is confusing. There is no difference, they are both a rate. What you've stated above (in my words and notation) is simply the forward rate between time 1 and 2 is the same as the spot rate in the future at time 1 until time 2. meanwhile, DF from time 1 to 2 is just the PV of a cashflow at time 2, at time 1, ie: not present value'd back to time 0. Does that clear it up?

Comment: I am still very confused about notation at the moment. Is your forward rate $f_{1,2}$ known at time t=0, or only at time t=1. Because if it is only known at time $t=1$ then I understand that it is equal to the spot rate. But in my fixed income course we have defined forward rates earned over a period in the future (say $[3,4]$) while this rate is already known now (say t=0).

Comment: it is implied today by the formula:
\begin{equation}
(1+r_{0,2})/(1+r_{0,1})=(1+r_{1,2})=(1+f_{1,2})
\end{equation}
so if you had 1 dollar, you would be indifferent between investing it in r(0,1), at which point you have the amount 1*(1+r(0,1)) and then invest it again at (1+f(1,2)) for the next period, or just investing it and getting back $1*(1+r(0,2)) you and the counterparty would be equally well off at the end. The 1 period rate at t=1 could in reality be very different, but that is irrelevant to our no-arbitrage formula today!

Comment: Think about it in terms of contractual agreement no-arbitrage, which is why i think there is some merit to talking about f and r separately. that is, you can enter a contract that you will get the rate $f_{1,2}$ which is very different from what $r_{0,1}$ could be, one period in the future. regardless of $r_{0,1}$ in the future, you and the counterparty would have already agreed on a set forward rate. Keep in mind that for an actual swap, you do not have such a 'contract' on the floating rate, and hence the value of the swap changes when the floating rate deviates from implied forward rates.

Comment: Consider investing a dollar for 2 periods. Three options: A) invest it at a locked in, known rate $r_{0,2}$ B) simultaneously invest it for one period at a known rate $r_{0,1}$ and lock in a rate $f_{1,2}$ so that you can take the dollar+interest at t=1 and invest it at $f_{1,2}$. the implied rate that you will get in a rational market equates the final value to option A. Option C) Invest at $r_{0,1}$ for 1 period, then roll over into the new 1 period rate $r_{0,1}$ at t=1. You are exposed to the risk of not knowing what rate $r_{0,1}$ at t=1 will be, so options C is NOT equal to A and B.

Comment: Valuing the floating leg of a swap uses the theory from option B to price the leg and imply floating rates (by the forward price formula). However! in reality, we do not know that the floating rate will in fact be equal to the forwards we implied! If we could (no point in practice) lock in each of the forward rates for the cash flows on the floating leg, there would be no logic to entering the swap! (you made a 0 NPV contract that does not change in value = always worthless!) Thus it is the deviation in realization of the floating rates as time passes vs our implieds that alters the swap value

Comment: I completely agree with your analysis of the three options A, B and C.  However, it seems to me that the formula \begin{equation} P_0(t_2)/P_0(t_1)=P_1(t_2) \end{equation} equates option A to option C, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: it does not equate to option c, only a and b. Option C is "reality". although forward contracts do in fact exist, A and B are used to price the swap at 0NPV initially. however as time passes, if your floating rate is higher (lower) than initially implied by the swap then you will have lost (made) money by paying the floating leg of a vanilla swap.

Comment: You helped me way more than I could ever ask, thank you. I will need to figure out my misconceptions on my own now!

Comment: you're welcom. it's not an easy concept to grasp! keep at it.